# WordPress Search throws Invalid Post Type with products page in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, search, woocommerce, filter

If I search in the backend (in products fx.) it works fine the first time, but if I do a second search on the 'already searched' item, it throws an Invalid Post Type.

URL in first search:
http://site/wp-admin/edit.php?s&post_status=all&post_type=product&action=-1&lang=en&product_cat=hair-care&product_type&stock_status&product_brand&filter_action=Filter&paged=1&action2=-1

URL in second search:
http://site/wp-admin/edit.php?s=&post_status=all&post_type=Array&_wpnonce=c3b7b5349b&_wp_http_referer=%2Fwp-admin%2Fedit.php%3Fs%26post_status%3Dall%26post_type%3Dproduct%26action%3D-1%26lang%3Den%26product_cat%3Dhair-care%26product_type%26stock_status%26product_brand%26paged%3D1%26action2%3D-1&action=-1&lang=en&product_cat=body-care&product_type=&stock_status=&product_brand=&filter_action=Filter&paged=1&action2=-1

and I see error message invalid post type

In the second search if i change http://site/wp-admin/edit.php?s=&post_status=all&post_type=Array&
Array => product it will return true result

Any help would be much appreciated.